# How to display one view in another view page

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have this below code where i want to display only "Welcome to my 3rd Blog!" of "blogvieww.php" in 
"blogview.php" using codegniter. But the below code what i tried with is that, even "Welcome to my 2nd Blog!" of "blogvieww.php" is getting displayed in "blogview.php".
actually i just want to display only  "Welcome to my 3rd Blog!", how to do this can any one tel me please im not getting where im going wrong.

Blogcontroller.php(controller file)

```
    <?php  
        defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');  

        class Blogcontroller extends CI_Controller {  

            public function index()  
            {  
                $data['blogvieww'] = $this->load->view('blogvieww', '', TRUE);
                $this->load->view('blogview', $data);  
            }  

            public function blogvieww()  
            {  
                $this->load->view('blogvieww');  
            } 
        }  
    ?>
```

blogview.php (view file)

```
    <html>
    <head>
            <title>My Blog</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div><?php echo $blogvieww; ?></div>
            <h1>Welcome to my 1st Blog!</h1>
        </div>    
    </body>
    </html>
```

blogvieww.php (view file)

```
    <html>
    <head>
            <title>My Blog</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h1>Welcome to my 2nd Blog!</h1>
        </div>

        <div>
            <h1>Welcome to my 3rd Blog!</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your can do simply using `$this->load-view('view_name')`, like following :

**view1.php**

```
<p>View 1</p>
```

**view2.php**

```
 <html>
  <head>
   <title>My Blog</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div>
    // Load View 1
    <?php $this->load->view('view1'); ?>        
    <h1>Welcome to my 1st Blog!</h1>
   </div>    
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: sir i think you did not understood my question

Comment: i just want to display a section of one view page in to another view page i don't want to display the whole page

Comment: You can also do this, in my example check `view1.php` has only paragraph tag which include in `view2.php`, You can't get the particular part of view to show in another view

Comment: "You can't get the particular part of view to show in another view", its not possible ?

Comment: Yes, if you need common part of view then create view and add it then use it with `$this->load->view()`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want,  but you can anytime to var_dump the value of $data['blogvieww'],  and if you want make a view section, don't use double  tag